# 1 request vs 2 requests to web service from iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, nsurlconnection

I'm working on iPhone app and I'd like to find out what's the best logical way to do the following:

From the app I have to send `member_id` and `event_id` to web service when user taps a button. I am using `NSURLConnection` and its delegate methods.

There's 2 things that need to happen:

1. Both (`member_id` and `event_id`) need to be inserted in table A on the server
2. Based on `event_id` web service has to respond with array of photos from table B.

What is proper logical way of doing this?

- Make one request and have the web service function handle insertion and response **OR**
- Make 2 requests at the same time (1 request to a function that will insert into database and second request to another function that will respond with photos)?

Keep in mind that I'm only sending `member_id` and `event_id` in both examples.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to design a web service API. That may sound simple, but the opposite is the case. The "client" never makes such decisions, rather it "adapts".

Once the web service API is set in stone, you try your best to implement the corresponding client API on iOS.

So, your task at the end of the day would possibly be to send a POST request whose content is JSON:

```
{
    "member_id": 1234567,
    "event_id": 7654321
}
```

What that JSON contains is defined by the web service API. Don't bother what the web service is doing with it - just give it what it requires.

Comment: I am designing the web service and that's exactly where I come to doubts. What is the proper way or best practice to do this. I understand the flow, I'm just wondering is there a right way or wrong way. Should I create create web service for 1 request or 2 requests based on the example above?

Comment: How to design a web service is a too broad question that cannot be answered in a brief and detailed answer. In an attempt to answer your question: aim for a RESTful API. This basically implements CRUD. For example, the "Create" method maps to a POST request. The request data contains "things" as opposed to "actions". What you get in a response are "things" as well. So, when a user tabs that button, ask yourself: does it "create", "read", "update" or "delete" a "thing" in the database? What are the properties of the "thing"?

Comment: Well it does both. With one tap on button it has to create and read. Should that be 2 requests or 1 request. I know I can do it both ways but what is the standard proper way.